# how to view ssas analysis services roles using nodejs

Tags: node.js, service, ssas, analysis, olap

how to view SSAS analysis services roles and assign that roles to related users
using programming languages like **nodejs**
I have tried PowerShell code but i dont know how to assign roles;just i saw roles

```
$SourceInstance = "SERVER\Node"
$RoleName = "BUSINESSROLE"
$Username = "DOMAIN\USERNAME" [System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices") | Out-Null
$mySourceServer = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$mySourceServer.Connect($SourceInstance)

[Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Database[]] $mySourceDatabases = @()
$mySourceDatabases = $mySourceServer.Databases

foreach ($mySourceDB in $mySourceDatabases)
{
    [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Role]$myRole = $null
    $myRole = $mySourceDB.Roles.FindByName($RoleName)
    if($myRole -ne $null)
    {
        Write-Host " $mySourceDB : " -ForegroundColor Green
        foreach ($myMember in $myRole.Members)
        {
            if( $myMember.Name -contains $Username)
            {
                Write-Host "   " $myMember.Name -ForegroundColor yellow
            }
        }
    }
}
$mySourceServer.Disconnect()
```